# castle windsor container register custom wpf button

Tags: wpf, button, castle-windsor

I have a WPF project and use Castle Windsor. I added a custom button class and add the button in the wpf window like this:

```
<Controls:CustomButton Name="TestButton" Content="TEST" Width="100" Height="50" 
                                MyProperty="1">
</Controls:CustomButton>
```

This is all working fine.

But how do I have to register/add this custom button to the container (IWindsorContainer), so I can use the other Services, which are already registered/added to the container.

I want to use this (e.g. when I click the button):

```
public IWindsorContainer Container { get; set; }  
var myService = Container.Resolve<IMyService>();
```

My problem is that the container is always null.

thanks, best regards Phil